# Why does my systemd service shut down immediately after running?

Tags: scripts, services, systemd

I created a simple script to run four other commands.  I have it located at /usr/local/bin/lbrystartup.sh, and it contains the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Start web scripts

screen -dmS main /var/www/html/main.sh
screen -dmS loop2 /var/www/html/loop2.sh
screen -dmS blocks /var/www/html/blocks.sh
screen -dmS lbry /var/stratum/run.sh lbry
```

When I run this script, it works fine.  I end up with four screen instances in the list, and they're all running as necessary.

Next, I created a service for systemd to run on startup.

coinscripts.service looks like this:

```
[Unit]

Description = Coinscripts daemon
After network.target = auditd.service

[Service]

type=Simple
ExecStart =/usr/local/bin/lbrystartup.sh

[Install]

WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

I've enabled the service, and it's successful in doing so.  However, when I run the service with "sudo systemctl start coinscripts", the screen instances don't open.  But, when I use systemctl status coinscripts, I get the following:

> > ● coinscripts.service - Coinscripts daemon    Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/coinscripts.service; enabled; vendor pres
> >     Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2017-06-30 21:59:10 PDT; 1min 3s ago
> >     Process: 1050 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/lbrystartup.sh (code=exited,
> >     status=0/S  Main PID: 1050 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
>
> Jun 30 21:59:10 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Coinscripts daemon.

Same happens when I restart the machine.

What am I doing wrong with the service script?  I'm using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: What does `screen -list`say? As the service runs as `root`, maybe you have to run that as `root`.  Or look for sockets in `/var/run/screen` via `sudo ls -lR /var/run/screen`.

Comment: When running the service, screen -list says there are no running screens.

Answer (score 0):

Are you still having this issue? This is more of a comment than an answer, but I apparently don't have enough points or whatever to comment...

I'm having a somewhat related issue on 18.04. Are you on 16.04?

I notice that you have an error in your After= section. should be:

```
After=network.target auditd.service
```

Not sure you really need the auditd.service there, but I think it should be ok. Also, you have:

```
type=Simple
```

which I believe needs to be:

```
Type=simple
```

The ExecStart line may also be having a problem with the equals sign (try deleting the preceding space), but I'm not sure how systemd handles the spaces, so that may be fine.

Lastly, I think you may want this to be Type=forking, since you are calling a child process in screen that will not exit upon completion.

Edit:

I also just realized that you're not using absolute paths in your script (i.e. /usr/bin/program instead of just program). Try that too.

I also would like to throw in a suggestion to use tmux instead of screen. In my experience screen is not very robust and often crashes, and tmux is a much better implementation of the same service. The commands are different though, so read up on those if you do decide to try it.